# Define Class object validations

Tags: crystal-lang

Is there a native way to define validations for a Crystal object ?
Let's consider this class:

```
class Person

  def initialize(@age : Int32) 

  end

end
```

How could I add a simple validation `if age < 18` ? 
Ex:

```
Person.new(10)
>> Error: attibute 'age' should be greater than 18
```

I saw a 3rd party library doing this but I'd like to avoid adding dependencies.

Comment: I think this is too broad. What would you like the validations to do?

Comment: It's a simple example that would help me achieve more advanced stuff but I want to make it easy to give an answer as per SO standards. But I'm editing my answer with an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no automated way to achieve runtime validation, but there is an idiomatic way:

```
def initialize(@age)
  raise ArgumentError.new("age must be 18 or more") if @age < 18
end
```